# How can I detect how long a key has been held down?

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard, delphi-7

I'm looking for a way to detect how long a key has been held down in a Delphi project and warn user.

I'm working on a chat program and need to see if the person is holding down a letter, like the W key, to spam that chat box. I'll give sample what trying to do in Delphi 7:

```
//Looking up if key in use and held for lets say 20 seconds
if (GetAsyncKeyState(Byte(VkKeyScan('W'))) shl 20) <> 0 then
begin
  ShowMessage('W Key Held down too long!');
end;
```

I'm not sure whether GetAsyncKeyState will give me that information, though. If it doesn't, what will?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to listen for `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages?

Comment: There is a keyboard repeat rate / repeat delay (system-wide parameter), that may vary for each user. I think you should take that into account.

Comment: IIRC, the windows message for a key press actually includes the number of repeats that have been generated.

Comment: What if someone *hack* your protection simply by pasting a long text from clipboard ?

Comment: Comments are valid, but I find this question interesting nevertheless..

Comment: @mj2008: MSDN says the repeat count is not cumulative, though.  You don't really need the actual count, though, just have to know if the message is a repeat or not.  You can get that info from bit 30 of the message's `wParam`.

Answer (score 4):

Windows does not report the duration of how long a key has been held down, only that the same `WM_KEY...` message is being repeated for a key that is held down.  You have to keep track of the duration yourself manually.  When you detect a `WM_KEYDOWN` message with its `wParam` bit 30 set to 1, if you are not tracking that key yet, start tracking it and store the current system/tick with it, otherwise grab the current system/tick time, calculate the duration, and act accordingly.  When you receive a `WM_KEYUP` message, stop tracking that key if you are tracking it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the StopWatch class in the StopWatch unit to check for timing.  Here's how you could try using it for what you're trying to do:

```
uses StopWatch;

//in the Form's private declaration:
  StopWatch : TStopWatch;

//in the Form's onCreate:
  StopWatch := TStopWatch.Create(nil);

//in the Form's onDestroy:
  StopWatch.Free();

//in the form/box onKeyDown:
  StopWatch.Start();

//in the form/box onChange:
  if (StopWatch.ElapsedMiliseconds > 1000)
    ShowMessage('W Key Held down too long!');

//in the form/box onKeyUp:
  StopWatch.Stop();
  StopWatch.Start();
  StopWatch.Stop();
```

There are likely lots of other ways to accomplish what you're trying to do though.  But for a quick try this should work.

The reason I stop and start the stopwatch again onKeyUp is to clear out ElapsedMiliseconds, in case the user changes the box with some method other than the keyboard, after having been alerted -- so they won't get alerted twice.